# How do I update rosdep rules for OSX?

Tags: rosdep, macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Fuerte, how do I update the rosdep rules for packages like PCL, OpenNI, etc?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32934/how-do-i-update-rosdep-rules-for-osx?/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at these [instructions](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html) hidden away in the Fuerte release announcement.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3